# jQuery Ajax scripts do not work on mobile browsers (any kind)

Tags: jquery, ajax, mobile-browser

jQuery Ajax scripts do not work on mobile browsers (any kind). It works on any kind of desktop browsers and in a their simulations of mobile. But when uploaded on production server and tried to execute from any mobile phone, it does not work.

```
let check_mobile = false;

<?php if (isMobile) { ?>
    check_mobile = true;
<?php } ?>

alert('ok');


$('.prod-img-wrap').each(function(ind) {

    let imgs_scope = {},
        front = $(this).find('.js-itm-hover-img-front'),
        back = $(this).find('.js-itm-hover-img-back'),
        img_front = front.attr('data-img'),
        img_back = back.attr('data-img'),
        id = front.attr('data-id');

    imgs_scope[id] = {
        'img_front': img_front,
        'img_back' : img_back ? img_back : null,
    };

    setTimeout(function(){

        $.ajax({

            url: 'index.php?route=product/category/product_thumb_work',
            type: 'get',
            data: { ids_imgs: imgs_scope },
            dataType: 'json',

            success: function(json) {


                front.attr('src', json[id]['img_front']).addClass('m');
                back.attr('src', json[id]['img_back']).addClass('m');


                if ($('.js-itm-hover').length > 5) {

                    if (ind === 5) {

                        filters_ajax();

                        <?php if (isMobile) { ?>
                            filters_mobile();
                        <?php } ?>

                    }

                } else {

                    if (ind === 0) {

                        filters_ajax();

                        <?php if (isMobile) { ?>
                            filters_mobile();
                        <?php } ?>

                    }

                }

            }

        });

    }, ind * 300);


});
```

Comment: jQuery Ajax does work on mobile browsers (any kind i have tested). Your issue must be somewhere else, like the CSP or your implementation. You should start by adding an error function to your Ajax so that you can share here what is the error you get.

Comment: Could the problem be in `let`? I know that not every browser supports this yet. If that's the case, simply changing it to `var` would do the trick.

Comment: smth like error: function(){ alert('error'); }, does not trigger at all

Comment: no, let is definitely not a problem

Comment: you should update to the not deprecated jquery ajax syntax as a start (done / fail / always replacing the success / error / complete). This is probably not the guilty, but you never know..

Comment: @Kaddath yeah, that is only idea I have for now, but my attempts to work out that question are too long for now, I wonder if I miss smth simple (not in my code, but in the idea of how to realize at least xmlhttprequest so it could work on mobiles)

Comment: So why aren't you using an error handler to find out why?